# Github Pages, Jekyll. How to define output page for posts?

Tags: github, jekyll

I am new to github pages and am currently trying to build a blog for my Design Studies but can't seem to get my post to output to the correct pages.

Currently all posts are being posted on the home page but need to be displayed on their appropriate course pages.

https://angusharrison.github.io/Design/
https://github.com/AngusHarrison/Design
Here is my sidebar menu

```
    <menu class="sidebar-menu">

  <li class="menu-items"><a class="menu-links" href="{{site.baseurl}}/">Home</a></li>
  <li class="menu-items"><a class="menu-links" href="{{site.baseurl}}/about/">About</a></li>        
  <li class="menu-items"><a class="menu-links" href="{{site.baseurl}}/INDN211/">INDN211</a></li>
  <li class="menu-items"><a class="menu-links" href="{{site.baseurl}}/INDN241/">INDN241</a></li>
  <li class="menu-items"><a class="menu-links" href="{{site.baseurl}}/INDN341/">INDN341</a></li>         
</menu>
```

When creating a post i would like to be able to output the post to the desired Page e.g https://angusharrison.github.io/Design/INDN211/

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You have posted two links. Can you verify which is the homepage and which is the `appropriate` ?

Comment: Home: https://angusharrison.github.io/Design/  CoursePage: https://angusharrison.github.io/Design/INDN211/  Repo: https://github.com/AngusHarrison/Design

Comment: Please specify more exactly, maybe with some code examples, what your issue is.

Comment: Updated post. All i am trying to do is get my post to be outputted to the desired page, currently they are all posted to the home page.   e.g Post "211-Reserch" should be outputted to : https://angusharrison.github.io/Design/INDN211/

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your Github repository, and here are the results:

Instead of single fixed links you currently have in your sidebar.html like

```
<li class="menu-items"><a class="menu-links" href="{{site.baseurl}}/INDN211/">INDN211</a></li>
```

use this in your sidebar:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  <li class="menu-items">
    <a class="menu-links" href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This loops over your posts in the root of your _posts folder and it is using the title from the front matter of each post. You could easily add something like `linktext: anyvalue` to the front matter of each post and use `post.linktext` instead of `post.title` in the loop as link name.

The post files should be named like `2020-02-02-anynameyoulike.md`, remove the seconds(?) from your filenames. And, there should be no subfolders.

Additionally I removed this from your _config.yml, as your question is around posts, not collections, it seems that you don't need that:

```
permalink: ':title/'

collections:
  INDN211
  INDN241
  INDN341
```

Optional, but I recommend to remove any `collection: anyvalue` and `permalink: anyvalue` from the frontmatter of your posts. You don't need them.

Result:

[image]

I recommend to read this page about posts https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/
as well as the rest of the Jekyll documentation :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Christian!!! I have created my collections but now my pages are 404'ing Can you please expand on "link targets / page urls or with your layouts (post pages using the same layout as your index page"

Comment: Updated my post.

Comment: Thanks for your help you are amazing. I am hoping for the side bar/ website to have links  to each course(as previously), so that tutors can be directly linked to there appropriate page and view all related posts

Comment: Related posts and posts per category or whatever are a different topic. Though it would be good to fix the navigation first :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help :)